# Python json module has no attribute 'dumb'

Tags: python, json, module

im having a problem currently where I get an error when im trying to use the dumb function from the json module.

My function which throws the error:

```
def writeToLocalJson(data):
    with open(DOWNLOAD_LIST_FILE, 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as outputFile:
        json.dumb(data, outputFile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        outputFile.close()
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'json' has no attribute 'dumb'
  File "C:\Users\kevod\Documents\Projekte\Git\downloadListe\testing.py", line 3, in <module>
    json.dumb()
  File "C:\Users\kevod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\kevod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\kevod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

Interestingly in another function im using the load function from the json module and it works correctly.
After searching for some time I only found solutions where there was another file called json.py which was imported incorrectly but this does not seem to be the case here.
If im running `dir(json)`  Im getting:

```
00:'JSONDecodeError'
01:'JSONDecoder'
02:'JSONEncoder'
03:'__all__'
04:'__author__'
05:'__builtins__'
06:'__cached__'
07:'__doc__'
08:'__file__'
```

Running `json.__file__` I get:

```
C:\\Users\\MYUSER\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\json\\__init__.py
```

Comment: You're looking for `json.dump(s)`

Comment: Okay, I deserved these downvotes :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function is called dump, not dumB*, that's all the problem as I think. So if correctly, it'd be

```py
def writeToLocalJson(data):
    with open(DOWNLOAD_LIST_FILE, 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as outputFile:
        json.dump(data, outputFile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        outputFile.close()
```